# Rubymine seems not seeing debug gem

Tags: jruby, rubymine, jrubyonrails

I am new to the RubyMine + JRuby on Rails, but I face a problem debugging the application.
The rubymine always prompt me a message

```
Gem ruby-debug-base is not installed
```

and show the following if I force it to debug

```
Error running Development: untitled1: Cannot start debugger.
Gem 'ruby-debug-ide' isn't installed or its executable script 'rdebug-ide' doesn't exist.
```

which I found is not correct, it actually installed
and the path of RubyMine is correct to the JRuby one

```
jruby -S gem list
actioncable (5.0.0.rc1, 5.0.0.racecar1)
actionmailer (5.0.0.rc1, 5.0.0.racecar1, 4.2.6)
actionpack (5.0.0.rc1, 5.0.0.racecar1, 4.2.6)
actionview (5.0.0.rc1, 5.0.0.racecar1, 4.2.6)
activejob (5.0.0.rc1, 5.0.0.racecar1, 4.2.6)
activemodel (5.0.0.rc1, 5.0.0.racecar1, 4.2.6)
activerecord (5.0.0.rc1, 5.0.0.racecar1, 4.2.6)
activerecord-jdbc-adapter (1.3.20)
activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter (1.3.20)
activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter (1.3.20)
activesupport (5.0.0.rc1, 5.0.0.racecar1, 4.2.6)
arel (7.0.0, 6.0.3)
babel-source (5.8.35)
babel-transpiler (0.7.0)
builder (3.2.2)
bundler (1.12.5)
coffee-rails (4.1.1)
coffee-script (2.4.1)
coffee-script-source (1.10.0)
columnize (0.9.0)
concurrent-ruby (1.0.2 java)
connection_pool (2.2.0)
daemons (1.2.3)
erubis (2.7.0)
eventmachine (1.2.0.1 java)
execjs (2.7.0)
ffi (1.9.10 java)
globalid (0.3.6)
i18n (0.7.0)
jar-dependencies (default: 0.3.2)
jbuilder (2.5.0)
jdbc-postgres (9.4.1206)
jdbc-sqlite3 (3.8.11.2)
jruby-openssl (0.9.15 java)
jruby-win32ole (0.8.5)
json (1.8.3 java)
jubilee (3.0.0.beta2 java, 2.0.0 java)
linecache (1.3.1 java)
loofah (2.0.3)
mail (2.6.4)
method_source (0.8.2)
mime-types (3.1) 
mime-types-data (3.2016.0521)
minitest (5.9.0, default: 5.4.1)
multi_json (1.12.1)
net-telnet (default: 0.1.1)
nio4r (1.2.1 java)
nokogiri (1.6.8 java)
power_assert (default: 0.2.3)
psych (2.0.17 java)
puma (3.4.0 java)
racc (1.4.13 java)
rack (2.0.0.rc1, 1.6.4)
rack-test (0.6.3)
rails (4.2.6)
rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
rails-dom-testing (1.0.7)
rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
railties (5.0.0.rc1, 5.0.0.racecar1, 4.2.6)
rake (11.2.2, default: 10.4.2)
rdoc (4.2.2, default: 4.2.0)
react-rails (1.7.1)
ruby-debug (0.10.6)
ruby-debug-base (0.10.6 java)
ruby-debug-ide (0.6.1.beta2)
sass (3.4.22)
sass-rails (5.0.4)
sdoc (0.4.1)
spoon (0.0.4)
sprockets (3.6.2, 3.6.0)
sprockets-rails (3.0.4)
test-unit (default: 3.1.1)
therubyrhino (2.0.4)
therubyrhino_jar (1.7.6)
thor (0.19.1)
thread_safe (0.3.5 java)
tilt (2.0.5)
turbolinks (5.0.0.beta2)
turbolinks-source (5.0.0.beta5)
tzinfo (1.2.2)
tzinfo-data (1.2016.5, 1.2016.4)
uglifier (3.0.0)
websocket-driver (0.6.4 java)
websocket-extensions (0.1.2)
```

Using

```
jruby 9.1.2.0 (2.3.0) 2016-05-26 7357c8f
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.91-b15 on 1.8.0_91-b15 +jit [mswin32-x86_64]
```

and

```
RubyMine Version 2016.1.1
```

I have no clue how to get it works,
can anyone give any directions?

Thanks

Comment: I finally understand what is happening here in Ruby >= 2.0 version, the ruby-debug-gem is not supported for those version and hence I cannot use them. Just leave this solution for those looking for the one face the problem as I do.

Comment: This seems to be a jruby 9.0.5 vs 9.1 issue, as I have/had this successfully working with jruby 9.0.5 and it fails when switching the project to 9.1

Comment: Now that I went from 9.1.0.0 to 9.1.2 and run my app in the context of bundler, it works again.